# Angular 4: Detect idle user using angular-user-idle

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-user-idle) library to detect  if user is idle in my application. I am using `StartWatching()` and in `onTimerStart` I am just printing console for now.

When the user is idle for N seconds, the  `onTimerStart()` is triggered. Which, logs the user out `onTimeOut()`. Fine.

Problem is, I cant seem to figure out how to reset timer when user becomes active again. Like I have a timeOut of 15 sec, on 30 sec idle time, so user isn't active for  30 seconds and timeOut countdown starts, if the user comes again after  the timeout countdown starts, it should stop the countdown and let the user resume without logging in again.

Can I achieve this? Appreciate any answers.

Comment: can you share code for better understanding?

Comment: have you tried `this.userIdle.resetTimer();`?

Comment: @Ingila I am having the same issue, how did you managed to resolve it? I am stuck where to call resetTimer()

Answer (score 0):

Please try with using `this.userIdle.resetTimer();`

Reference
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-user-idle